# Htaccess domain.com to www.domain.com works, but it loses other rules related to SEO

Tags: .htaccess, seo, dns, url-rewriting

EDIT: **FIXED**

Well, after stumbling around this site and Google for a few hours, I found the problem:

Bad code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Good code:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The REQUEST_URI seems to not work like $1... so I'm learning mod_rewrite the hard way.

---

The question:

Conditions:

- basic rewrite rules for SEO urls
- domain redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com

Problem:

The  non-www.domain.com pages lose their SEO-urls and turn back to the original php variables:

Ex.

SEO-url: **www.domain.com/Video+1234**

NonWWW url:     **domain.com/Video+1234**

Result (browser address bar):

**www.domain.com/index.php?video=1234**

Desired:

**www.domain.com/Video+1234**

How can I make the server keep the old form?

**.htaccess snippet:**

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /



RewriteRule ^Video\-(.+)\+([0-9]+)$ index.php?video=$2


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after stumbling around this site and Google for a few hours, I found the problem:

Bad code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Good line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The REQUEST_URI seems to not work like $1... so I'm learning mod_rewrite the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^Video\+([0-9]+)$ http://www.domain.com/index.php?video=$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`L` in first rule will make it stop after applying that rule. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @anubhava I have multiple rules for multiple php files. I used that one just for example.  The full URL in the rewrite rules don't solve the problem from my tests. Actually it made the normal *WWW* urls like '/Video+1234' type urls turn into  '/index.php?video=1234'.      ....  so, with the config you mentioned:    **www.domain.com/Video+1234** becomes **www.domain.com/index.php?video=1234** - which is the opposite of what I want :D

Comment: You can treat that answer an example as well and apply same concept to all of your redirect rules. As long as you are doing internal redirect no `[R]` and have `[L]` flag it will only handle that rule and should not mess up anything else.

Comment: I noted in your question you have `^Video\-(.+)\+([0-9]+)$` in rewrite rule but trying to match text `Video+1234` which will fail. So I changed your regex to `^Video\+([0-9]+)$` So Just edited my answer above, please try again.

Comment: @anubhava By changing the regex the php script doesn't register the variables, so I didn't even check the non-www url.  The `www.domain.com/Video+1234` I made is an example, but my urls actually are longer, like `www.domain.com/Video-Not-another-lolcat+1234`.  Results: no php variable registering (and different php errors according to the existence of `[L,NC]` flags)

Comment: @anubhava OK, I've also tested the main issue (my question) and it still makes the php variable urls, besides not registering the variables themselves

Comment: In your index.php just place this line at the top `<?php var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_URL"]); echo "<br/>"; var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]); ?>` and then with above rules (as in my answer) when you visit `http://www.domain.com/Video+1234` pls tell me what you see in your browser by copy-pasting the results.

Comment: I'm doing this on a live site :)

Comment: You can enclose above in html comment like: `echo "<!--";` and `echo "-->"`; :)

Comment: brb forgot to change the htaccess

Comment: @anubhava Well, the source shows nothing except two empty lines. Not even the comment echo.

Comment: I used this php script: `<?php echo "<!-- "; 
var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_URL"]); 
echo "<br/>***"; 
var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]); echo "-->"; ?>`    ... it's probably due to some security measures.

Comment: It really beats me. I really needed some debug info to move forward here. Not really sure what's causing this php code to eat output :(

Comment: Either way, the new lines haven't been able to maintain the "SEO url" content.  I'm still wondering how other people do it.  Maybe if I ditch the htaccess  nonwww-to-www solution and use some apache <virtualhost> `Redirect` stuff, it would work, but I'm a noob at apache and wouldn't know where to place the code to make it work without crashing the site.

Comment: I have used these rules many times and they've worked every time (you can see my SO profile and dozens of answers I have given on this topic) . In your case since I am not getting any debug info I can't really do more to help you out.

Comment: I can't find the exact debug info and the timecode is weird :( . There has to be some solution where there's no need to work with the php side.

Comment: @anubhava I found the solution and edited the main question. Whoo... that was hard.